# Webサーバー(Apache2.4)でmod_rewrite モジュールを読み込む方法

Tags: linux, centos, apache

### 【質問の主旨】

Webサーバー(Apache2.4)でmod_rewrite モジュールを読み込む方法を教えてください。

### 【質問の補足】

#### 1.

【質問の主旨】に関するサーバーなどの環境は以下の通りです。

```
サーバー: さくらのVPS
OS : CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core) 
Webサーバー : Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
```

#### 2.

Webサーバーにおいてmod_rewriteを読み込む理由は[こちらのサイト](https://e-yota4.com/)でWordPressのREST APIを有効化するためです。先日、WordPressフォーラムで[質問](https://ja.wordpress.org/support/topic/pwa%e3%82%92%e5%88%a9%e7%94%a8%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b%e3%81%9f%e3%82%81%e3%81%ab%e5%bf%85%e8%a6%81%e3%81%aaweb-app-manifest%ef%bc%88json%e3%83%95%e3%82%a1%e3%82%a4%e3%83%ab%ef%bc%89%e3%81%af%e3%81%a9/)をしましたが、mod_rewriteモジュールの読み込む方法については他の質問投稿サイトで行った方が良いと考えて「スタック・オーバーフロー」で質問しました。

Comment: 検索ワード「さくら　VPS　mod_rewrite」で検索すると結構な数のサイトがヒットしますが、その方法ではうまくいかなかったということでしょうか？どのあたりまで設定を進めてダメだったか記載されたほうがアドバイスが集まりやすいと思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。「WordPress mod_rewrite」・「mod_rewrite 読み込み」などのキーワードでGoogle検索をしていて、「さくら　VPS　mod_rewrite」では検索していませんでした。質問するときはどんなキーワードで検索したかも説明するようにします。今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS 7 標準の Apache 2.4 のパッケージ `httpd` に含まれる `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf` で最初から `mod_rewrite` をロードする設定が記述されています。こんな↓内容の行。

```bsh
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

この設定ファイルは Apache httpd の設定ファイル `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` で読み込むようになっています。こんな↓内容の行。

```bsh
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
```

現在の設定でどのようなモジュールが有効になっているかは、次のように `httpd` コマンドで確認できます。

```
# httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
...省略...
```

この出力では `mod_rewrite` モジュールは `rewrite_module` という名前で表示されるので、`grep` などで絞り込むときは注意してください。

```
# httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES |grep rewrite
rewrite_module (shared)
```

`httpd` パッケージをインストール後に `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` などを書き換えて `mod_rewrite` を読み込まないように設定したのであれば、適宜該当する設定を戻すなどしましょう。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。サーバーを確認したところ`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` と `Include conf.modules.d/*.conf` はすでに記述されていました。そのため `# httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES` を実行したところ `rewrite_module (shared)` と結果がかえってきました。
ただ`# httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep rewrite` を実行すると `AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:44 rewrite_module (shared)` と返ってきますが、mod_rewrite モジュールはすでに読み込まれていると思います。
今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いします。